# Database insert script for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I have a requirement where data from 150 tables with different columns should be copied to another table which has all these columns. I need a script which will do this activity automatically instead of manually inserting one by one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the column names from either `sys.columns` or `information_schema.columns` along with the datatype, then it's just a simple matter of de-duping the columns (based on name) and sorting out any conflicts with differing datatypes to create your destination table.

once you have that, you can create and execute all your insert statements.

Good luck.